# Must I download entire WP directory for each separate instance/website that uses WP?

Tags: php, installation, ftp

I'm no noob when it comes to website design or development. And am quite savvy with JQuery, XHTML and PHP. However, I admit I am quite noob-ish when it comes to WP...

I already have the WP directory (folders for includes,admin,content and all the other php files it requires) uploaded to my root. Well, obviously in a subdirectory of the root (ex. root/wordpress).
My question is, if I'm creating multiple (different clients) websites with WP yet stored on the same host, do I need to fully install the entire WP directory again? This time under a different pathname (ex. root/wordpress02)?
I'm pretty damn sure the answer is yes, as each instance of WP has its own Dashboard and makes calls to its own PHP files. Unless I changed the target path of the plugins and other files I plan on sharing amongst my different WP sites, the answer is **yes**.

I'm pretty sure I just answered my own question -- it's 1 am here. I've had a long day...
but I'm still kinda curious how you guys go about installing multiple instances of WP on your root. Just append a number to the different directories? (ex. root/wordpress01 , root/wordpress02 , root/wordpress03)

**Thank you!**

Comment: Is it on a VPS you control or is it a shared hosting? Usually, shared hosting have a set www-root (at least in my country).

Comment: @LeaCohen MU is deprecated and instead moved into the core as WordPress Networks. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share the same wordpress installation for multiple sites/blogs, I'd suggest looking at [WordPress Networks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network). And if you need different domain names (and not just subpath or subdomain) you could go with the plugin called [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/).

*If you have lower level access to your server (and not just a shared hosting) then you could probably create a link to the wordpress installation from all your sites root, but that would just open up for so many problems.*

Comment: If you're developing 2 completely different WP-based websites that are to be hosted by you (for completely different clients), how should I go about uploading those sites? Just in a different directory each containing the entire WP install folders? 

For example: Company A's site in one subdirectory containing the entire WP install
             Company B's site in another/different subdirectory containing yet another instance of the WP install.

Comment: That's usually how I do it. I find it easier to maintain when each project has a separate core since plugin dependencies can vary so much. It's such a hassle when one site requires one WordPress version and another site requires another version due to some necessary plugin which hasn't been updated. What do you mean by sub directory? Are they under the same www-root and just placed in separate directories? E.g. `http://site.com/company-a/` and `http://site.com/company-b/`?